# "map" an array in Typescript typing

Tags: typescript

I have a command parameter interface here (These are put in array `command.params`)

```
export interface CommandParam {
  name: string
  resolve: (input: string) => unknown
  onMissing?: () => unknown
  onFail?: () => unknown
}
```

This method processes inputted arguments and returns values which types are determined by the return type of `CommandParam.resolve`

```
  private async resolveParams (
    command: Command,
    args: Array<string>,
  ): Promise<{[k: string]: unknown}> {
```

How do I replace that `unknown` return type with an array of the types? To demonstrate what I want, regular script to accomplish this would be (Not actual working script because of ReturnType, but this is demonstrating my point)

```
command.params.map((p) => ReturnType<typeof p.resolve>)
```

I'm pretty sure this is possible because something similar is done [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=36&ssc=4&pln=36&pc=10#code/PQKhFgCgAIWgVAFgU2gYwPYDsAuyAeO0AlgM7Q4CeADsVgObkBmGATtAIbQBSAytABtiAIwA00YQFciASQDkAW2gB3YgKENoACg5YAJtALVkaHFFgUU0LMmR6AlBQyc9B0jklMmg4gGtU9Mg2rMRo5BzkAtj0nOQ4KJTouipsvuZwqvEY0uiIuoFxzvGofD7CJDikyAJMAHTQAILqlqhoAhFV5CisqBw96dAAbsisiaTECtRCTMR2QyPj2KTimLgcdHQx2AKJPQLIg7pE1H2V9enAUFCgEDBwSKjEeshc3Y9xeURcPRzP7KrNHAcfwkLDUHK6AwcHB4SZEHAYAYnVhVTjQUjGNDEGZoCg0ZD1AAKrAwwg4wh20Ho2CwXBscy4gWCoRczwMb1qFygbQ60AASi8-gAeeAAPmgAG9zNAZQpkFk9Fp7AAuaDEjAKMjIEXigA+CEl0plxugPQ8rCwkoAvrFOFhKEboFaoM7INcwAMGpaMNQcMRsNAWOwuJgFApIZy7pdIDzSOQGqx6JI5bghQA5QyEIJ6cjuEIMcRiw0wY20uUAQlVaYA3I6fn9K-zBSMdbW3SWZas85JTGwtGXkFXxPWRqqBb8W2LHFKOybLGRagPoABeawcOWOk3xBcj9ir3eO12u923CxpjBEPYHI6Btjz0iR2DR2PkADC2DwhElTqukGAwGgABRfATn0aBw38ch4H4UNhDoR5cAWEw-SWKAqGMNUQk1P1hhXdEcHzGJ9SwZNhBGaB9WEDAMH2ZJKOIeg6CIfVSEoBQqIECjrEkZp9UkfRkBmGw9DbdDUGA0C9B1PD4EzPB9HIYkJmIHDUAAfgNVUJWgABtABpUFoH8SgMG8eAAF1VXgfTzKdNtrgA3ggX0PoDAmKZAxJJREBhahSGVf93A4NBfAwYZWCYKJlFqUNgAAR0kZB3H9LBSGAABWAAGABmAB2AAWABOTKAA5gAI3RSCDBQAFp+JSmqxMajAaqYpDTAasS0PxaAAFUsBS+AMBkRCUWQlKhV68VV2lLRerk7NwntaANK0XxVV6+xl1FQYMCeaBVRscLHAIeSc20NbVToJhyJkLadr2hwVugGQDusA4Rl-bqMIaZR1jwKSi1XWTTsWzCNS1AAZPxtWu8i+XFDS+Te+B7MgMToAAcXlBNGBFBaFNNQVtkSXHkyCHAhTzTZxH43wsAwZQsFFHTzOmoCQMhSaBuwIaRrwMaOuwIUZxNfTDOM0yEEshAbIJ86yZTSm4fYNNxBV-lEeLOdjX0gAmQy0xl37-rsIUEcPN6js+yArR0kj2JGNnRV-G5PXQDVwzA+JoSSS0yMzExpDsR8QGfdo42gd8w0hbXjT6JMlf8onfhJxpE3J1NqYLaA6YZpmWfMtGTS7AiewRVgdETZPo69vQdLkBPM8qORzOnTdjW3B8m6TvCE9IQ9fxNN3ZwsV9JFYHpcEpfuSDifEoXIPPGctWOhHKSQqhRP3oGeITkE3OBkjaiLgtQYoFCqARhmWCQcle5RsgEAwhBBBFd6KRAyFvdgL8PkhvDUAwHGEQ+x6gPHTonCm4RJ4cESACTi1t2BoDyAwXoYEyD-z3vBAwAZS6sHLilcQpB1yoEyIgJsE5t6x2KETdwj4TRhzrPxLQqxPw4FVO+RChBxD9zUqqZeTMVTg01FUIUu0nh6iGI9b8R5fyl04NXPCOlHQ2GUJA5uWhG5yHENpOUColTfjNBPS0ABGJ0Vp7CiFUcgdRisKZaOEDo78+jEAYEVNOIm5pLRyDkBY+wUBbIRA9qlMw7YFFpl4LXSE5jVxqKjp7SEVdGABPbJE6J+hTG1AIZaVcrCPynV4YmVU2McC41IEKMSUt+6ikcNtOOnYlg0QJFEegyS1K1A4EU+gHThCpOPDGCO5B0mJP0AbUGhMMkGFFvHDOvdVz9yHsaHJ+TuEcISWs7p-CsY42rpU-E1Tq61IaXOLszTaitPaZ0rZtQ+mD1tkAA)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question.  Please consider modifying the code above so as to constitute a [mcve] that others can drop into a standalone IDE to demonstrate your issue for themselves.  It's possible you want something like the following.  If so, I'll write up an answer. If not, please elaborate.

Comment: [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)

Comment: I'm not really sure what writing this up would help with. I guess you misunderstand the question. I would like the return type of `resolveParams` to be an array of types that are defined by the return types of the resolve methods of the `CommandParams` in the supplied `command.params`

Comment: So if `command.params` is `[{ name: "foo", resolve: x => x.length },{ name: "bar", resolve: x => x.toUpperCase() },{ name: "baz", resolve: x => x.length > 5 }]`, you want the return type of `resolveParams()` to be `[number, string, boolean]`, right?  If not, please explain explicitly what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want

Comment: Great, that's what the code I linked four comments ago does (click the "this"; it goes to a TypeScript Playground snippet).  Look at the type of `x` in that code; it is `Promise<[string, number, boolean]>`.  Can you verify that this code does what you're looking for?  If so, I will write it up as answer, explaining how it works.  If not, or something is missing, please tell me what it is so I can make sure my answer applies to your question.  Good luck!